# Why Do I Get a Blank Page on an Error but other people don't

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I am watching [this video](https://youtu.be/gWlEUcUZ3kI?t=47) and when an error occurs he gets an actual error on the page and only a blank white screen when he deploys the site.

I see this a few times. However I only see white screen no matter if I am on local host or on production.

I see he is using chrome on Mac and I am using it on PC. Not sure if that is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't say definitively, my suspicion is that you aren't using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to setup your project.

You will only see that error message if you have used CRA to set up your project, as that is a specific error handler that is baked into that project. If you're not using create-react-app, React should log an error to your console instead.

Comment: And only if it is running from the dev server. \

Comment: This is probably it, I did not use the CRA and setup my project myself. I did not know that was a feature of it. I really will have to look into using it in the future projects.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS smart enough to hide the errors to the users when the app is in production mode.

You will see only a blank page if the app gets crashed but if you inspect the page you will see small detail about the error in the console.

if you running the app in development mode you will see full details about the errors.

for this case cames `componentDidCatch` method to handle app crash errors, instead of the blank page display a “***Something went wrong***” message to the user or you can send XHR request to the server with the error info.

Check out [this example of declaring and using an error boundary](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010)

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html